# Where can I download RE2?

Tags: regex, re2

I'm working on a project using .net, C++, that needs regular expression, I don't want to write a Regular Expression Engine myself, besides the performance is so important for me, I found that Google's RE2 is almost the fastest, but I can't open "code.google.com/p/re2/" :(
Would you tell me where can I download it? I'm searching, but all the refrences send me back to "code.google.com/p/re2/".
TNX

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Install ?

Comment: I can't see this page either! I got "forbidden error"

Answer (score 2):

You can download the source code using [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) and compile it yourself, as explained [here](http://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Install?tm=4):

```
$ hg clone https://re2.googlecode.com/hg re2
$ cd re2
$ make
```

Be warned, though, that no effort has been made to ensure it will compile on Windows. You might have to tweak things a little to achieve that.

Comment: But I got "Forbiden" Again, on the second link :( Do you know why? I'm from PERSIA, is this the problem?

Comment: @rain, yes, your network appears to be the problem. Apparently, Google [is blocking connections](http://jadi.civiblog.org/blog/_archives/2007/5/1/2917242.html) from Iran.

Comment: I hope that our government leave us alone! Thank you, I'm downloading Mercurial. I hope it could help me.

Comment: @rain, It is **Google** who is enforcing sanctions against Iranians. Nothing from our government in this regard.